# How to change length to 2 decimal places?

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to work out how to calculate the length of a line to only 2 decimal places in QGIS. When I use the field calculator to create a new field, it doesn't matter what changes I make to the field type, field width or precision, I continually get the length to 13 decimal place.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the latest dev QGIS version there is a new round function which you can use to control the number of decimal places:

```
round($length,3)
```

Result: 1.10228762876525 -> 1.102

Comment: I guessed that there would be a simple expression, thanks Nathan

Comment: when 1.9 rolls out?

Comment: 1.9 is not being released.  2.0 is the next release hopefully in the next few months.

Comment: where do i insert this function in the field calculator  (in qgis 2.18)?

Answer (score 6):

You need to save the file, before the changes to precision are fully displayed.

Comment: In QGIS Master, you also have to leave edit mode and/or close and reopen the attribute table.

Comment: I work with QGIS 2.8.6 and this function doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Best solution:

Load plugin : "Processing", Spatial data processing framework for QGIS

Select commandos in the menu bar "processing"

Type "field" in combobox

Select: "Processing algorithm: Refactor fields"

Set decimal positions in the fields

(If there are any items in the expression column are  signed red just add "......" at begin and end (shapes don't like long column names with a space (so for example: column x coord has to be "x-coord")

Save to new file or temporally (so you can overwrite your excisting shape).

Done