# The number of digit of decimal point when you calculate area of polygon in QGIS1.8.0

Tags: qgis, area

I would like to change the number of digit of decimal point when I calculate area.

For example
Now: 32.456677
Ideal: 32.46

I try to adjust "output field width" and "Precision"
These don't work well.

Let me know how to adjust the number of digit of decimal points.

Comment: You are right!! I got success. Appreciate!

Comment: @JermainMarthin: I'm glad it helps! I've posted my comment as an answer, it would be good if you could mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The rounding to two decimal places is only applied after you click "Save" in the Field Calculator. Setting Precision to 2 and Width to something large like 10 should work.

Comment: In QGIS Master, you may also have to leave edit mode and/or close and reopen the attribute table. There is also a new round function in Master, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/47981/how-to-change-length-to-2-decimal-places