# Reducing decimal places in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, decimal-points

I'm using QGIS 2.18 (Las Palmas).

I want to change the length of the decimal place, I tried the approach in [How to change length to 2 decimal places?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/47981/how-to-change-length-to-2-decimal-places) however, it still displays 13 decimal places.

Comment: Which QGIS 2.18.x version are you using? In the Attribute Table, you could _right-click_ your column name and select the `Hide column` option. For changing the length of the field, you could create a new real field from the **Field Calculator** and copy over the values from the old column using an expression like `"original_column_name"`. Or use the **Refactor fields** tool from the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: I'm using QGIS 2.18.3. Thanks for your help, i'm a little bit ashamed that i didnt even think of trying to right-click!

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that each thread should be limited to one specific question only. You can check our [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information. I've removed the already answered (and probably duplicate) question about hiding columns.