# QGIS area label too many decimal places

Tags: qgis, round-function

In QGIS 3.4.4, I've set a field to double numeric, precision 1, to give a useful value for hectares. The field shows `nn.n` but the label goes to loads of decimal places.

I've tried `round` but it doesn't do anything (mostly). I've looked at a number of threads, including this [How to change length to 2 decimal places?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/47981/how-to-change-length-to-2-decimal-places) but it's not working.  If I set it to `round` only, I get the non-decimal rounded figure, but if I specify 1 or 2 places, it is ignored. I've checked & rechecked my expression `[  round ("Area ha",1)  ]`

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the round() function in the label panel of the layer properties or just in the field calculation?

Comment: I went into the expression builder from the label panel, which then popultes that box with the expression. Are you suggesting that I may get  a different result if I type the expression in there directly, without using the expression builder?EDIT just tried that & get the same result

Comment: Using the label expression first is a good and quick way to troubleshoot errors like this rather than trying to run the field calculator every time and having it fail... it should be the same syntax give or take...

Comment: `round` should do... You can try `format_number("fieldname",1)`, which outputs a string instead of a number

Comment: I'm stumped. The expression you typed *should* work.

Comment: `round()` function had a bug until QGIS 3.4.4-3. Please, upgrade QGIS to latest LTR or stable version.

Comment: How is this Off Topic? Please help me understand the nuances of SE.